# How do I change the font of my UISegmentedControl to the "Light" styled system font?

Tags: swift, fonts, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to change the style of the text in my UISegmentedControl. I want to use the system font but the "Light" style of it. I understand how exactly to do this in terms of the line of code, literally just need the **string** to establish the Light system font. I have tried "System-Light" and some others but it keeps resulting in an error, yet any other (custom) fonts work fine.

i.e. :

let attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "**WHAT GOES IN HERE????**", size: 13.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject], forState: .Normal)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a system font, instead of the standard UIFont constructor use the class method `UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize, weight)`.
For the light font use the UIFontDescriptor constant `UIFontWeightLight`.

For reference see [UIFont](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/index.html) and [UIFontDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html) class references.